# Timer job is not running on all servers in 2007 MOSS Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, timer-jobs, server-farm

We have shifted our MOSS 2007 Solution from one Server machine to another server machine. On old server after deploying corresponding `.wsp` file, our custom timer job runs on all 3 servers `sess1`, `sess2` and `sess3` in the MOSS 2007 Farm. But When we have shifted our solution to new Server machine and deployed the same `.wsp` solution file, the same timer job only runs on one server `sessNew1` where SharePoint central admin is installed.On other two servers, job is not showing. The other two servers `sessNew2` and `sessNew3` with that timer job are not showing under timer job status.

Any idea, what is wrong?

Comment: what are the server roles in the old and new farms?

Comment: How to check server roles?